# Ingest data into Graylog from Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, graylog2

I'm asking out a question to the community on a requirement I had. I have been using Graylog for my system monitoring which works great. Right now, I'm trying to see if I could use Graylog to ingest the data records which I stored in a Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express for analysis.

As the data comes from various SCADA devices, and it has to be retrieved from the SQL into Graylog for further analysis.

I would like to know if there is any method which I could achieve this requirements.

Thank you.